# addToSet mongodb not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Current document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53d9c7654dfe220f0e8b45bb"),
    "cd" : 1406781202,
    "op" : [
    {
        "fr" : "test test"
    }
],
}
```

I want to update "op" only like an example below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53d9c7654dfe220f0e8b45bb"),
    "cd" : 1406781202,
    "op" : [
    {
        "fr" : "test test"
    },
    {
        "hi" : "test 123",          
    },
    {
        "mp" : "test abc",          
    }
],
}
```

In the above example "fr" index exists before update and I have added "hi".

Please let me know the query?

Is this an ideal way to achieve this? ie I am saving the data in "op" with indexes fr, hi etc so this field should like this only?

Comment: What the provided answer fails to explain is that this is not an array type. `$addToSet` is for arrays which is what you really should be using. Using values as "keys" is bad news.

Comment: Yes true I want to use "op" as an array type but in that case I am not able to update fr or hi because in that case I have to use Push and pull...tell me if I am wrong

Comment: The "op" field is not presently an array. Are you actually asking how to change it into one?

Comment: I can make it an array...but in that case how I will update fr or hi fields??? because in that case I have to use PUSH and PULL....so please suggest me solution..."op" can have multiple indexes and I want to update them as well..

Comment: @NeilLunn pls comment?

Comment: @NeilLunn question edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I was generally getting at is you seem to be using "values as keys" which is an anti-pattern that you should not follow. The original post did not even show an array but still the structure is not much better.

You should have something like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53d9c7654dfe220f0e8b45bb"),
    "cd" : 1406781202,
    "op" : [
        {
            "key": "fr", "value": "test test"
        }
    ],
}
```

Then you can push elements into the array as follows:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": ObjectId("53d9c7654dfe220f0e8b45bb") },
    {
        "$push": { 
            "op": { 
                "$each": [ 
                    { "key": "hi", "value": "test 123" },
                    { "key": "mp", "value": "test abc" }
                ]
            }
        }    
    }
)
```

And in this way you only make one index for your collection over all of the options.

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "op.key": 1 })
```

And you can also query like this:

```js
db.collection.find({ "op.key": "fr" })
```

Rather than using operators that cannot use an index such as **`$exists`**

```js
db.collection.find({ "op.fr": { "$exists": true } })
```

Which is what you would be currently stuck with.

Answer (score 0):

db.collection.update({"_id" : ObjectId("53d9c7654dfe220f0e8b45bb")}, {$set:{"op.hi":"test  45"}})